# How to create mapping for geopoint properties using fluent api and attributes in Nest?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, nest

I am trying to configure mapping for geopoint property using **Nest v5.5.0**

I have this model(type) **Address** which has this property:

```
 [GeoPoint(Name = "coordinates")]
 public Coordinates Coordinates { get; set; }
```

The Coordinates class:

```
    public class Coordinates
{
    [Number(NumberType.Float, Name = "lat")]
    public float Lat { get; set; }

    [Number(NumberType.Float, Name = "lng")]
    public float Lng { get; set; }
}
```

and using the fluent api:

```
.Mappings(m => m
      .Map<AdvertiserType>(map => map
                 .AutoMap()
                 .Properties(p => p
                      .GeoPoint(geo => geo
                             .Name(n => n.Coordinates)
                                )
                            )
                      )
     )
```

But When I try to index data I got parse exception.Could please tell me how to map geopoints properties using Nest5.5.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use NEST's `GeoLocation` type](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/47c2123eb328220bf5aba35c901016f352c28123/src/Nest/QueryDsl/Geo/GeoLocation.cs#L15-L15) which will be mapped as a `geo_point` [using automapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html)

Comment: But why the value of lat and lon are Long, and they don't have decimal points (eg 19.5547)?

Comment: @SimpleCode they're not `long`, they're `double`: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/47c2123eb328220bf5aba35c901016f352c28123/src/Nest/QueryDsl/Geo/GeoLocation.cs#L20-L29